# SpriteRenderer Image getting stretched down

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I had a spriterenderer for a square but I want to change it from looking like a basic rectangle to having an image instead. So I tried changing the sprite renderer "Sprite" to the image I wanted but whenever I do so the image is looking pixelated, ugly and stretched and I can't rescale it properly.

Before:[image]

After: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The image may look ugly because it is stretched. In your hierarchy, select the GameObject with the SpriteRenderer. Then set the x,y,z scales back to 1.

If it still looks weird, select the image in your assets folder, and play around with the quality & filter settings (Don't forget to click apply). Hopefully this helps with making the image look nicer.

If not, ensure that your image asset is not a low resolution either.

I'm not really sure what you mean about it not rescaling properly. If you could please elaborate then hopefully we can fix it :)

Comment: Hello I haven't tried your suggestions yet but I surely will. And to elaborate, in the pictures I provided you can see how the after image becomes smaller in width but larger in height. You can kind of see the camera preview outline on the left side and you can then see how much the image has been stretched out.